# how to prevent spam bots from joining groups in Telegram?

Tags: telegram

I have a group in Telegram that is bombarded by spammers/bots.  We have Shieldy enabled, which gets rid of *most* of the spammers within a few seconds, but the notifications that come a few times per day get really annoying. There is no setting in the group setting that is able to prevent it.  How can I restrict the group so that only *invited* people can join the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be entirely avoided.

Change the group settings to "Invite link" in Settings > Manage Group. Revoke the permanent link to regenerate it.

That should reduce your visibility to only "Groups nearby" and require the invite link for anyone else. BUT invite links can be easily generated and tested for validity by a spam bot.

Add a bot like Shieldy (https://botostore.com/c/shieldy_bot/) to your group. It will further aid in restricting new members capabilities, especially bot ID's and uses Captcha verification. Bots can kick genuine people though so watch it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Scripts are mostly used in the same way as they are used to create a tracking list to check offline/online users in some messagge applications versions for the web. Through this same way Java compiled with BOTs of Telegram app are doing their job in this sense. The disadvantage of that is they often self-add themselves to huge groups ans because they are linked to Rose and GroupHelp BOTs they are the same used as a helpful tool to get rid of unwanted users from TG groups. But as a matter of recent facts, 2020-2022,such BOTs have been compiled with too many privileges. That's why these are themselves a Spam for TG itself. SpamInfo Bot oftenly got confused by IDs. In short, when these numbers are too short are BOTs and when missing a certain middle in the binary code number also, because the numerical ID of TG is a synthesis of Location, Machine Location or IP of the machine used by the user at the moment of the account creation and registration, plus a number based on an code relating to the phone number prefix of the users. BOTs can not have a geo location and their machine location is standardized. Recently a fork version of TG it is told to reveal the server locations (i.e. Singapore for Asian users, Miami or Florida for American users, Netherlands for European users). Yet this does not reveal which user is a BOT or if they are redirecting the things which they write through a BOT (which is already possible in TG through Anonymize BOT). With Java great things has been accomplished, seamingly but at this purpose this is a hindrance, in my humble opinion. And since machines and IPs are revealed in TG, the app is losing its "privacy focused" reputation. That's the fault of how the BOTs has been conceived and of a malicious usage of Java and Python.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).